# Define typescript function signature from union of types

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-typings, conditional-types

I want to define the type of a function from a union of types:

```js
type MyEvent =
| { type: 'hello', payload: {} }
| { type: 'start', payload: { date: Date } }


type On<Event> = Event extends { type: infer EventType, payload: infer EventPayload }
  ? (type: EventType, callback: (payload: EventPayload) => void) => void
  : never

const on: On<MyEvent>
on('hello', (payload) => void)
```

but the compiler defines the type of the first argument as "never"

The On returns a type that seems good. I tried the raw type returned as well, with the same result:

```js
type RawOn =
| ((type: "hello", callback: (payload: {}) => void) => void)
| ((type: "start", callback: (payload: { date: Date }) => void) => void)

const raw_on: RawOn
raw_on('hello', (payload) => void)
```

How can I define "a union type of function signature" ?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCiA3CA7YUC8AoAPlA3lKJAFxQDkAFhADY0D25ANFGAIYgNsAmZ%20AvlH64CRcBDLkAzsDYAnYM1YcuvUdzbAJUACKbog4VizFoAeRQAeJKmAA%20TFBtooEAB5aU3KaNNkAligAZhByTshoACriLOyc9DwBwaHhtgAKKgncQlhQUAD8UAAUfqlRMVAAxmx0AEZslQDWZEVxqmTOwBnxPACUmA6I9P7c-RiDw9y5UGQoEMhyxpX0KDJQK2QWlnCddlgrRVS0DEqtmX0DUEMjvcYA9HdQALQvr2-vH59f3%20-GplAAJTYAHcLJgREUSuIyAAiah0egwljVOoNZrFNpZPj8MYTG6Xa6jCFQ0hQGEyeTAJFVGo0epNFqYxLqfRkPRaIS4q6TLmE25YZardByEEAfQ2gJBFiwIuB4pQh3hJxYZx6owJPOMQA)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @cherryblossom for the solution:

```js
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void)
  ? I
  : never

// --------------------------------------------------
  
type MyEvent =
| { type: 'hello', payload: {} }
| { type: 'start', payload: { date: Date } }


type On<Event> = UnionToIntersection<
  Event extends { type: infer EventType, payload: infer EventPayload }
    ? (type: EventType, callback: (payload: EventPayload) => void) => void
    : never
>

const init_on = (): On<MyEvent> => {}
const on = init_on()

// OK
on('hello', (payload: {}) => {})
on('start', (payload: { date: Date }) => {})

// ERROR (that is OK)
on('hello', (payload: { date: Date }) => {})
on('bad-event', (payload: {}) => {})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCpIJJ2BATgZwgGNhk4AeGAPigF4oAKGKCADxzgBN8oBDOEFAD8jANYAuWAEo6NAG5IEnKJLgQ5eGWw7dGDCVARwAZnigYZteYs5SAUFGHmHKqGo247dgPTeoAWkCg4JDQsPCIkJc7UEgoAFkQAFENbDo7AB8oAG8oWIhJAHIACwgAGzKkQoAaKDBeEEreTklsgF8oNsycvPACqEL8YF5cYBq6hqaWns5eHEkAETnoDq6vfKgAeQoUiGwaengydCwcAmJSFHIXXbTtPd1c-MkjU1woW+BUPtr6xqRmi8TGZPgAFSYA5RdRyOEQMZ4fVJfH5QIi8CoAI14RAMDD+U0kYIhzUs1iUpKgCiULkcqnUeDsVC8RBQQ0MiGAAH0UHRGFJJNtyIlPgcaO07Cy4GyefQjAguSgGPYfH5NgBpOyKkrlSrjPHE6btClGzVwBiDYajPX4yGtKCzeZQJY4TrGtrK3wfABKXs2XsYwGKc0MPHV9i1pQqVVq+v+gJmy0Wy1dshy7tN5qxnH89Ow1oNrXdqaNQA)